# Easy Pie Chart no effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts

I recently used the plugin **easy-pie-chart**: rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/

On the page, I've included the js file

```
<script src="vendor/easy-pie-chart-master/src/easypiechart.js"></script>
```

I add this code

```
<div class="chart" data-percent="73" data-scale-color="red">73%</div>
```

and recalled the plugin

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.chart').easyPieChart({
        //your configuration goes here
    });
});
</script>
```

It does not appear, however, **no result**, belonging to the number written in the normal manner.
What is the reason?

The console gives me error like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'easyPieChart'
```

Some of you could help me: **I thank you all in advance**

Answer (score 5):

I think `easyPieChart.js` path is not correct ,check the path or give

```
<script src="http://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/javascripts/jquery.easy-pie-chart.js"></script>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/aqMN4/346/)**

Comment: Thanks for the 'help, the result is this: jsfiddle.net/VPKDA/

Where can I find the css code you used?

Comment: http://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/stylesheets/jquery.easy-pie-chart.css.      plugin CSS

Comment: There are 3 different versions of easypiechart. If you are using Jquery based and you are in an angular cli bootstrapped application. Add below script in .angular-cli.json


**"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/easy-pie-chart/dist/jquery.easypiechart.js"
      ],**